# windows ReadFile() doesn't return when reading data from a HID device

Tags: c++, hid

I'm trying to write a program that sends and receives data from a HID device. The device employs ASTM protocol for communication. I'm using hidsdi.h library for communicating with the device. So far I have been able to get a handle on the device. I'm now attempting to send a message to the device so that it sends a response in return.

My Code:

```
HANDLE hDevice = CreateFile(devicePath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        // error…
    }

    char DataBuffer[] = "X";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;
    uint8_t * pTmpBuf = (uint8_t *)calloc(inputReportLength, sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t * pAppBuffer = (uint8_t *)calloc(inputReportLength, sizeof(uint8_t));
    DWORD nRead;

    if (pTmpBuf == NULL)
    {
        //return error(“memory allocation failed”);
    }
    try{
        if (pTmpBuf == NULL)
        {
            ;// memory allocation error…
        }
        //
        // copy data to be sent, reserving the 1st byte for report ID
        //
        memcpy(pTmpBuf + 1, DataBuffer, sizeof(DataBuffer));
        bErrorFlag = WriteFile(hDevice, pTmpBuf, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        free(pTmpBuf);

        pTmpBuf = (uint8_t *)calloc(inputReportLength, sizeof(uint8_t));

        if (!bErrorFlag)
        {
            bErrorFlag = ReadFile(hDevice, pTmpBuf, inputReportLength, &nRead, NULL);
            DWORD dwError = GetLastError();

            if (!bErrorFlag)
            {
                memcpy(pAppBuffer, pTmpBuf + 1, nRead - 1);
                free(pTmpBuf);
            }


        }

        CloseHandle(hDevice);
        hDevice = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
```

It seems that WriteFile functions successfully sends data to device however when the compiler tries to execute the ReadFile() function, the control is never returned and the execution just hangs. I haven't implemented any timeout function, I figured there would be a timeout by default but the compiler never gets to execute the next line after ReadFile.
I'm new to the ASTM communication protocol and there's loads of things I'm still trying to understand and wrap my hand around.

According to the documentation I have, the structure of the frame looks this:

```
<STX> FN text <ETB> C1 C2 <CR> <LF>
```

where each field has a certain ASCII value. Do I need to encode my message in that fashion when I'm sending data or sending char representation of the message is enough? like I have done in the code.

According to the doc, I need to do the following to get a response from the device:

```
1) Send “X” to the meter.
2) Meter responds with <EOT> HEADER <ENQ> within 2 seconds.
3) Send <NAK> to reject data transfer
4) Meter responds with <EOT> to indicate it is exiting the transfer phase.
5) Send <ENQ> to the meter to initiate sending remote commands.
6) Meter responds with <ACK> to indicate it is ready to receive remote commands.
7) Send remote commands.
Send <EOT> to the meter to indicate remote commands are complete.
```

I'd really appreciate someone helping me out.

The software guide for the device can be found [here](https://www.docdroid.net/17jQv9h/contour-next-usb-3rd-party-cis.pdf.html)

Comment: `compiler tries to execute` D) you must use `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` in `CreateFile` call and use asynchronous io. in this case will be no hangs

Comment: I have tried reading the data asynchronously but I never get any response back from the device.

Comment: this already related to your concrete hardware specific (which i don't know) - why device not complete read request. but always the best in this case use only asynchronous io